# Nest ignoring complex properties when retrieving mappings

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

When mapping a DTO like this

```
public class InnerDto
{
    public string Uno { get; set;}
    public string Dos { get; set; }
}

public class OuterDto
{
    public string One { get; set; }
    public string Two {get; set; }
    public InnerDto Three {get; set; }
}
```

If I try to retrieve the mapping using elasticClient, for example:

```
Client.GetMapping<OuterDto>(s => s.Index("test2"));
```

The mapping returned by the client is missing my "Three" property (the one that is a "complex" type).

Looking to the ElasticSearch response, the data is returned. I´m missing any options in the GetMapping call?

**Edit 1:** The response of GET test2/_mapping

```
{
  "test2" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "outerdto" : {
        "properties" : {
          "one" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "three" : {
            "properties" : {
              "dos" : {
                "type" : "string"
              },
              "uno" : {
                "type" : "string"
              }
            }
          },
          "two" : {
            "type" : "string"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Mind posting your json output from doing a GET /test2/_mapping?

Comment: @GregMarzouka of course, I´m editing the question to include the json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is a bug and has been fixed [here](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-net/pull/756).  Thanks for finding and pointing this out.

Comment: Great, thanks! Just a question, that fix is available in the nuget package?

Comment: No, not yet.  However, we are going to be releasing 1.0RC very soon, and it will be available then.  For now, you can grab our CI builds from here: https://www.myget.org/gallery/elasticsearch-net.